# Override for non-link phone number displaying as link on iPad?

Tags: css, ipad

I got a phone number for a site in tablet version that is displaying as a link only in iPad. It isn't tagged as a link, because that would be weird on a tablet, but I guess Apple defaults all phone numbers as links?

I have tried targeting this element specifically in CSS to remove the underline and change the font color, but nothing seems to work.

How can I fix this? It looks super ugly as a large blue underlined phone number on the page.

Comment: Try this http://litmus.com/blog/remove-blue-links-ios

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found solution - since I didn't target any links in my CSS, and Apple devices add < a > tags around phone numbers, I just added a new CSS property targeting < a > tags in the parent div so they would not show as links.

Answer (score 4):

To remove auto formatting of telephone numbers add the folowing tag to the HEAD of your HTML document:

`<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">`

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I do need phone links to show in the mobile version.